# Rails LEFT OUTER JOIN to load multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model called Entry that has_many :entry_states. EntryState has an attribute called :read.

I want to get all entries whether or not there is an entry_state so I think a LEFT OUTER JOIN is the best way to go see [Left outer join on Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

However I also want to include an attribute of EntryState in the result. So I have a query that looks like:

```
entries = Entry.select('entries.*, entry_states.read').
joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN entry_states ON entries.id = entry_states.entry_id AND entry_states.user_id = #{user_id}")
```

The problem with this is the entry_states object is not available after this.

I can get the read state like:

```
entries.first.read
>> t
```

Which gives me the raw column value, but this is a boolean column so it would be great to get back `true` or `false`

What would be even better is if I could get the whole EntryState object. I've tried using .includes(:entry_state), but I have not found a way to include the outer join condition of `AND entry_states.user_id = #{user_id}`